# Is it possible to add your own help file to the Delphi XE2 IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, helpfile

For a library I am working on, I have created a help file (Help 2 format). It would be very convenient if the other developpers of my team that use the library, could search the help from inside the Delphi IDE.

Is it possible to make Delphi XE2 search in a custom help file when I press F1 in the Delphi IDE? And if so, how should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is, the same way third-party component vendors do. As you say, use the free [Microsoft Help 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_2) compiler, Help 2 Workshop, available through MS.

Once you've written and compiled your help, you incorporate it into the IDE's help system via H2Reg.exe, which you can find in your `$(BDSDIR)\Help\Doc` folder. Read the comments in h2reg.ini (in that same folder) for details regarding how to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I got it all working now. I am using Doc-O-Matic to extract comments from my source code. It then generates an MS Helfp 2.0 file. The real challenge was to install the Help compiler from the VS2008 SDK... First extract the vssdk.cab and .msi from the setup, install it and use namespace.exe to register the resource.hxs. After that, the help file generated by Doc-O-Matic was easily added to the Delphi help file by using H2Reg, as you mentioned.